# PHP: Can I put an IF statement in a <li> tag?

Tags: php, html, html-lists

Ok so i'm trying to make a checklist for a school website and I want to make an ordered list followed by the check box and the description. Here is my code for it but I get an error message saying "Unexpected IF statement."

```
echo "<ol type='1'>
       <li>" . if ($r['check1'] == 1){
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1' checked>submitted my JSCC
                  admissions application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and Records
                  Services.
                  \n<br>";
       } else {
           echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1'>submitted my JSCC admissions
                  application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and Records
                  Services.
                  \n<br>";} . "</li>

       </ol>\n";
```

Comment: PHP and HTML are independent, there are no limitations to what and where you output HTML with PHP.  The problem is you can't use if in an expression.

Comment: right and as expected. Use the condition to check if it's equal to something, then echo, and vice-versa.

Comment: @Fred -ii- I knew the IF statement worked because I used it elsewhere in my program with no problems, my only issue was how to put it inside a <li> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code. Here you can use ternary operator like this.

```
<?php

echo "<ol type='1'><li>" . 
( $r['check1'] == 1  

        ? "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1' checked>submitted my JSCCadmissions application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and RecordsServices.\n<br>"
        : "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1'>submitted my JSCC admissions application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and Records Services. \n<br>"
) 
. "</li></ol>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make the if-else statement separate from the echo statement:

```
echo "<ol type='1'><li>";
if ($r['check1'] == 1){
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1' checked>submitted my JSCC admissions application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and Records Services.\n<br>";
} else {
   echo "<input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='1'>submitted my JSCC admissions application for the upcoming term to JSCC Admissions and Records Services.\n<br>";
} 
echo "</li></ol>\n";
```

Then it will execute correctly.